# rewrite for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to generate subdomains with a rewrite rule.
It should look like this:

http://www.example.com.dev/folder/default.html
to
http://folder.example.com.dev/default.html

This is as far as I've got it:

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com.dev$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).example.com.dev$ [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) %2/ [L]`

I'm pretty new to this, so can you help me?
Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close, try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com\.dev$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.com\.dev$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com.dev/%2/$1 [L,P]
```

Comment: Sadly, I get a 500 - Error.

Do you know how it may possible to read the index.html-file, which is in the insert and existing foldername?

Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I think you got error 500, because the rule was creating a loop. I edited my answer

Comment: Does someone else have an idea?

Comment: 502 means Bad Gateway (your server is not configured to work as a proxy server), then you have no other solution

Comment: Ok, I think it works now but
with this RewriteRule my URL will always be changed to www.example.com.dev/folder back again.
It should still be like this after loading the page. folder.example.com.dev/(no folder here)/images